# Is there any kind of hooks available in android which would let developer interact with other running applications?

Tags: android, hook

On windows we have different hooks, by which we are able to interact with any running programs. for example one can get a running apps handle and then change some its properties, etc .
I want to know if similar functionality is present in android systems.

Comment: Sorry it is not possible in android you can not interact with other apps or can not change its properties. You can just open that apps and you can also create apps that other apps can use your apps nothing else. Like if your code is for choosing pic from galley so number of possible application shows which contains pics like your gallary, Google Photos apps etc.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper, Thanks alot. by t he way does android allows for browser plugins and can apps communicate with a specific plugin in a browser or is this not possible as well?

Comment: Yes it is possible.As I already told in my previous comment you can access the apps but you can not change any code of that application.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for example one can get a running apps handle and then change some its properties, etc .

Yes, malware authors think that this facility is great.

> I want to know if similar functionality is present in android systems.

No, for blindingly obvious security reasons. On rooted devices, something like the Xposed Framework offers some of this sort of thing.

> does android allows for browser plugins

No. Neither does Windows, macOS, or Linux. Web browsers can allow for browser plugins. The exact details of how one implements a browser plugin will vary by browser and OS.

> can apps communicate with a specific plugin in a browser

That would vary by browser. My guess is that the answer is "no", but you would need to contact the developers of your browser of interest for confirmation.

Comment: Thank you very much, that clarified alot .
By the way, about the part where I talked about handles and interacting with  other programs, if the system allows for non-destructive interactions this would not be a problem. plus the first application would need to acquire permission to do so from the user anyway.
apart from these, is there a way where one can get the location of the current running apps as well? or getting such information is not possible either?

Comment: @Coderx7: "if the system allows for non-destructive interactions this would not be a problem" -- yes, it would. Google has been going to great lengths to limit the ability of other apps to find out what apps are running, for privacy and security reasons. "is there a way where one can get the location of the current running apps as well?" -- I have no idea what this means, sorry.

Comment: @CommonWare: Thanks, by location I meant the apps gui coordinates (x,y points), I want to know if getting some general information is possible, such as applications title text, its size, stuff like that.

Comment: @Coderx7: I hope not. That's **specifically** the sort of thing that malware authors want to exploit (e.g., superimposing a fake login dialog to intercept credentials).

Comment: @CommonWare: I have to disagree on that. if a malware was to be coded/developed , they usually target specific apps, with which one can easily pre-calculate the needed coordinates.  
for doing such things people wont be asking questions on SO. they will head toward the underground hacking sites and ask such there, where exploits and other shortcuts are available to them. 
Anyway, Thanks alot for your time and great help,
I see you have book on android, I'll consult with the book from now on.  I really appreciate it ;)

Comment: @Coderx7: "with which one can easily pre-calculate the needed coordinates" -- Android 7.0's multi-window allows the user to control location. Also, security-conscious apps will dynamically position critical dialogs, so that they are not in the same spot every time.

Comment: @CommonWare: Good to know, I didn't know that! but it can be circumvented pretty easily as well, for example by implementing a light weight inference mechanism using a simple dnn trained on those specific apps, this would let them easily identify both the exact windows, and their coordinates and plus the title of what ever section they need inquiry of .

Answer (score 1):

```
Each app in Android OS run in it's own sandbox. 
You cannot change behaviour of any other app. 
You can only communicate with other apps if they have 
the feature to do so, like when you want to share 
something in the app, then a  lot of sharing app opens. 
Like facebook, whatsapp, twitter etc. 
Beacause they are intended to do so. With the Deep Linking we can 
make out app to be connected with other app.
```